SBWFarm & SBFarm certificates expired & unable to renew - Everything hosted on the SharePoint 2019 Web Frontend Server
We have a SharePoint 2019 server with the (newer) SharePoint Workflow Manager, and ServiceBus 1.1 installed. All services are running on the same server (customer is a small company).
We are trying to update the expired SBFarm and WFFarm certificates. Before doing so we stopped all SharePoint-related services and set the system time back to before the self-signed SSL certificate expired. Then we attempted to update WFFarm and SBFarm certificates, eventually running into this error:
$ Set-WFCertificateAutoGenerationKey -Key $CertKey
----
Set-WFCertificateAutoGenerationKey : Auto-generation of certificate is not supported if user has specified certificate thumbprints.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Any ideas on how to rectify? I was following this article:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/spblog/sharepoint-201320162019-how-to-replace-expired-workflow-manager-certificates/1148650
Not seeing anything in the article related to this issue. Any help is much appreciated.

If anyone else runs into this, Microsoft Support had me run the following SQL commands on the WFManagement DB:
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'IsOutboundCertificateGenerated'
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'ServiceSSLAutoGenerated'
update [Store].[ServiceConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name= 'IsEncryptionCertifacteGenerated'

And the following commands on the SbManagement database:
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'IsClusterCertificateGenerated' 
update [Store].[ClusterConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'ServiceSSLAutoGenerated'
update [Store].[ServiceConfig] set Value = 'True' where Name = 'IsEncryptionCertificateGenerated'

Once that was done, we could issue new self-signed certificates using the process outlined in the above-mentioned hyperlink.

Helpful information!
